# Slide div right to left inside image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image and inside it I have a div that appears when hover the image. I want the exhibition of this div inside of the image be animated (slow), from right to left.

I got it so far from left to right but I just can't figure it out how to make it from right to left.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="slider-div">
        some text
    </div>
    <img id="image" src="img.png">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#image").hover(function(){
    $('#slider-div').animate({width:'toggle'},350);
});
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

#image {
    height: 170px;
    width: 140px;   
}

#slider-div {
    background: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: can you create a demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default your #slider-div starts from left:0; position. So it will animate to the right. If you want to make it left just position your #slider-div at the beginning as right:0;.

Answer (score 1):

```
#slider-div {
    background: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** It would probably be a good idea to use classes, which **can** be used more than once on the document and not ids, which can **only be used once** per document.

#### Want to simplify this with no jQuery?

For a simple hover action like this, jQuery seems like overkill and simple CSS can take care of all the looks here.

First, place the image before the slider div:

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/140X170">
    <div class="slider-div">some text</div>    
</div>
```

this allows you to target the slider div, when the image is hovered, with the [adjacent selector (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) to increase its width:

```css
.container img:hover + .slider-div {
    width: 50px;
}
```

The slider div is given:

- `right: 0` to stick it to the right
- `width: 0` and `overflow: hidden` to hide the text when not hovered
- `transition: width .3s`, to create a smooth, animated width change

```css
.slider-div {
    background: green;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    transition: width .3s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

#### Complete Examples

Only when the image is hovered.

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.image {
  height: 170px;
  width: 140px;
}
.slider-div {
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: width .3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container img:hover + .slider-div {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/140X170">
  <div class="slider-div">some text</div>
</div>
```

When any part of the container is hovered, using `.container:hover .slider-div`

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.image {
  height: 170px;
  width: 140px;
}
.slider-div {
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: width .3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container:hover .slider-div {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/140X170">
  <div class="slider-div">some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice. If I hover the "slider-div" (that is inside the image), it considers that image lost its focus, so it hides the "slider-div" and next it shows it again. Do you know how can I avoid this?

Comment: Of course :) I was just duplicating what the jQuery was doing. For the hover, just use `.container:hover .slider-div` and whenever any part of the container is hovered, the green div will show. Added an example at the bottom.